# How do I access an event in a foundry script?

Tags: foundry

I'm writing a foundry script, and I'd like access to an event emitted by a script.

Ie (pseudocode):

```js
// get the event from a tx
uint256 some_value_emitted_as_an_event = token.transfer(my_address, amount);

// use the event on a new function
token.balanceOf(some_value_emitted_as_an_event);
```

How would I do that?

Comment: The objective is to see the parameters that the event created or validate them? Do you want to see them from the script or on the console with verbose is enough?

Comment: I want to use the outcome of an event as an input to a new function.

Comment: Oh, let me edit the answer. It's solved using logs.

Comment: Is the token contract part of your repo or it's an external address?  If you aren't listening for logs on chain then you can import console.log function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `vm.recordLogs()` and then just get the logs and access them. Also please note that `vm.getRecordedLogs()` function will consume the recorded logs when called.

```
vm.recordLogs();

emit LogTopic1(10, testData0);
emit LogTopic12(20, 30, testData1);

// Notice that your entries are <Interface>.Log[]
// as opposed to <instance>.Log[]
Vm.Log[] memory entries = vm.getRecordedLogs();

assertEq(entries.length, 2);

// Recall that topics[0] is the event signature
assertEq(entries[0].topics.length, 2);
assertEq(entries[0].topics[0], keccak256("LogTopic1(uint256,bytes)"));
assertEq(entries[0].topics[1], bytes32(uint256(10)));
// assertEq won't compare bytes variables. Try with strings instead.
assertEq(abi.decode(entries[0].data, (string)), string(testData0));
```

This is the log struct, for more info use the reference link:

```
struct Log {
  bytes32[] topics;
  bytes data;
}
```

Reference: https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/get-recorded-logs

Comment: Right, but I want to use the event emitted as the input to a new function.

Comment: Edited to solve your question

Answer (score 1):

I would run the Foundry script with verbosity being set to at least 2.

Example:
`forge script script/MyScript.s.sol:MyScript ... --verbosity 2`

Reference: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-script?highlight=scripts%20event#evm-options

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, I'm looking to get the output of an event as an input to a new function.

Answer (score 0):

What in case we have 2 strings in event?

```
    event TestEvent(string someString, uint256 indexed someNumber, address indexed someAddress, string someOther);
```

Now to get above we can simply do below:

```
        someString = abi.decode(entries[2].data, (string));
        someNumber = entries[2].topics[1];
        someAddress = abi.decode(entries[2].data, (address));
        someOther = ???;
```

But ye what about "someOther" how can we access this second string?

I'm also not sure If I'm getting address parameter corectly...

I was not, correct reading address would be:

```
someAddress = address(uint160(uint256(entries[2].topics[2])));
```

Ok some nice guy gave me the answer on that, leaving it here for someone in need:

```
// Mapping unindexed data...                                          
(string memory s1, string memory s2) = abi.decode(entries[2].data, (string, string));

someString = s1;
someOther = s2;
```